# A problem with digital signal of voltage in the [0..60]V range

Tags: voltage, frequency

I'm rebuilding an old broken Leybold-Heraeus LH 57545 Timer/Counter.
It's a school lab instrument which the tech dep. cannot fix.
I'm not an electronic engineer, just a physics teacher with limited knowledge/tools.

Here is the problem: a pair of banana socket is supposed to receive a signal in the 0Hz - 1MHz range with voltage that can be in the 3.5V - 60V range. (the manual states: "Pulse input 4-mm socket pair (bottom socket to ground) for input of positive pulses up to 60 V").

I successfully measure frequency generated by a function generator feeding an 6N137 optocoupler and an Arduino Uno.

How can I handle signals > 5V up to 60V? I thought of a zener diode as voltage limiter, but, in case this is a valid option, due to my limited knowledge I don't know what's the right product. If you know a better solution, I'm glad to listen.

Comment: To be clear: you're building a completely new frequency counter?

Comment: if this is used in a school try to make it robust against all sorts of nonsense, including things like being plugged in backwards to mains power. Students will do that sort of thing.

Comment: I confirm: it's a complete rebuilding, replacing all existing hw with Arduino UNO and other components. Diodes added against reverse polarity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @nck666 Sounds like this for a student lab... is that so? I would tend to think you'd want something fairly robust. Do you have to deal with negative input voltages and count properly if the voltage is wired up oppositely? (It's safer to assume nothing about the operator. But that's your call, not mine.) Also, I think you are considering the use of the 6N137 in the final result -- which is a good device. I'd want to provide it with a consistent driver that works similarly all the way up to the maximum rate.

Comment: All sockets are reverse polarity protected with a 1N4007 diode. Reagrding the original LH counter, it was supposed to deal with low voltage signals (about 3.5V) as well with signals with fair greater voltage (60V). The consistent driver you mention is what I'm looking for. So far, no joy. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @nck666 You will have to use the dratted '@' in front of my name (the code here magically recognizes such things) to get my attention. I just accidentally dropped over to see your response -- 8 hours after you wrote it. Just FYI. You can set up a standard push-pull driver output that is driven by a common base BJT that can be used to achieve 1 MHz speeds. At least 3 BJTs. Maybe more. It should provide a consistent, repeatable drive for the 6N137 regardless of input range, too. I'll think about it. I'll be busy tomorrow, but may possibly find time over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

> *How can I handle signals > 5V up to 60V?*

<sub>I'm assuming, just for clarity, that the signal has a peak of 60 volts and returns to 0 volts. For a different meaning (such as for RMS signal levels), a different voltage divider ratio is needed with some mid-rail biasing.</sub>

So, start by thinking about the upper limit peak voltage. If it's 60 volts, you can attenuate that by 12 times (resistor divider) so that it reaches a maximum of 5 volts. That can be safely handled by logic or analogue circuits running on a 5 volt rail.

Then consider that the smallest signal is also reduced by 12 times using the same resistor divider. This lowers the peak of 3.5 volts to 0.29 volts and, this range of voltages (0.29 volts to 5 volts) can be easily interfaced to your logic circuits using a voltage comparator.

How you go from here is up to you but that isn't your question.

Comment: Resistor divider == Voltage divider, I suppose. But if measurement is performed in different context, and the upper limit peak is 5V, the vd provides just 5/12 = 0.4V.

Answer (score 0):

You can regulate the AC signal to give 5V AC output using this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLdxMm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It's DC. but concept is clear. Any diode in particular? Resistor value?

Comment: If its DC then you dont need 1 of the zeners.Resistor value will depend on the resistance of the load.

Comment: I dont know to suggest zener sorry , but if you find one with IZK  ~ 3mA and IZT~90mA then you are good.

Comment: thanks Miss Mulan. just 1 diode is fine.  IZK ~ 3mA and IZT~90mA specs are quite difficult to meet.

Comment: They dont have to be exactly 3 and 90 mA but not a full order of magnitude bigger.